# How would you style a PHP suffix with CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, text-formatting

I've setup a date object in PHP:  `$date_formatting = "l, M jS";`

Note the uppercase S to the right of the day (j).  This creates a suffix such as 3rd, 1st, 2nd.

The problem is I don't know how to go about targeting only the suffix for CSS styling.  I would like to make the suffix a smaller font size than the number.

Any clues?

Comment: Brad's answer uses semantic HTML to obviate unnecessary CSS styling according to what you're looking for (ordinal suffixes set in superscript); however if you wish to control the styles yourself regardless, you can pick nico's answer. Either way is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$date_formatting="l, M j<\s\u\p>S<\/\s\u\p>";`

What this does is puts the `<sup>` tag around the `S`.  This tag is for [superscript](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlsuperscript.php).

Comment: @Boltclock, thanks, I was just editing that now.  Verifying to make sure I got all of the escaped stuff...

Comment: Works great, styled it like this:  sup {vertical-align: super; font-size:65%;}

Answer (score 4):

Or, if you want to avoid the pain of escaping all of that...

`echo date("l, M j")."<span class='whatever'>".date("s")."</span>";`

Comment: @Joe, how is `<sup>` not "today's standards"?  It is part of XHTML 1.0 strict, XHTML 1.1 strict, and HTML 5.

Comment: @Joe, @Brad: In fact, `<sup>` has been around since HTML 3.2. It hasn't been deprecated, ever.

Comment: i think its kind of a qustion. of course sup is not deprecated. but it has a meaning. and if its just about styling and has no relevance to the content (and i think the question was about styling), i would prefer css.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_formatting = "l, M, j<\s\m\a\l\l>S</\s\m\a\l\l>";
```